# PHP - Array gets positions injected after N loops

Tags: php, loops, debugging, for-loop, whitespace

I am dealing with kind of an odd problem here. I have a `for` loop that goes through an array composed of various text lines previously input by the user with the following preset:

`Name`

`Data1 of Name1`

`Data2 of Name1` (This goes on for `DataN of NameX` as Data is a series of properties that the user chooses [i.e: 11 columns requires up to `Name + Data10`])

Anyway, everything goes smoothly until, at least on my test dataset, around loop 400, where the array output shows me

`Name`

Whitespace

`Data1 of Name`

Whitespace

`Data2 of Name`

When I test the problematic user inputs, deleting every one before them, and just pasting them as the sole inputs, ie: Copying Name and Data 400 and 401 and just pasting as Name and Data 0 and 1, no issue found, although around 100 cycles later, the `Name100 Data1` following seem to suffer the same problem.

TL;DR - PHP Seems to be injecting whitespace positions on my array after N loops and it seems to happen randomly but steadily after a few hundred loops. Can anyone enlighten me?
Many thanks.

P.S - I have double checked the dataset and there are no whitespaces where they're showing up.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($statisticsinput); $i++){
      if(strpos($statisticsinput[$i], "Total") !== false){
        if($step !== 2){
          $step++;
          for($k = $i; $k < $i+2*$_POST['columno']; $k++){
            unset($statisticsinput[$k]);
          }
          $statisticsinput = array_values($statisticsinput);
        }else{
          goto firststepended; //Please don't complain about the GOTO it really was needed.
        }
      }
      if($i % $_POST['columno'] == 0){
        $j++;
      }
      $employees[$j][] = $statisticsinput[$i];
    }
    firststepended:
```

Edit: Sample input as asked by HtmHell:

```
Name1



14 000

8 133

70 000

104 760

20 952

0

0

7 543 

10 476 

1º

Name2



9 000

4 796

45 000

34 177

6 835

-3 323

-15 823

0 

3 370 

2º
```

It is pretty much just this repeated with different values. There is no exact value when the whitespaces appear, they just do after a few hundred cycles.  The string is processed in a way that removes all whitespaces if the next line is not alphabetical. They are in positions where the next line is not alphabetical so they should have been removed if they were in the pasted text. But they are not there when pasted.

Comment: [A] You can use `break` instead of `goto` (PLEASE!) [B] I think the whitespace is not related to this piece of code, but to the `$statisticsinput` variable.

Comment: `break` (Which would be supposed to end the `for` loop) threw an error saying "Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context", which I read around and seemed fixable by using a `goto` which in itself does not seem to be a huge threat since it's only used to exit a nested loop

Comment: `goto firststepended;` line is inside the loop, so it shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, show us the `$statisticsinput` variable. How you set it? And give us the exact value when you get the whitespaces

Comment: Added to post .

Comment: You gave me a string, yet in the code you treat `$statisticsinput` as an array. What's the deal?

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was obvious. The input string is converted to an array by line.
`$statisticsinput = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['statistics']);`

Comment: You gave us little code to work with, so I'm not sure what's happening. But you have multiple line breaks in a row, then shouldn't this happen?

Comment: Replace your line with these two:
`$statisticsinput = preg_replace('#\R+#', "\n", $_POST['statistics']);
$statisticsinput = explode("\n", $statisticsinput);`

First line to make multiple new lines into one, and second one is like your code in the comment, but `preg_split` is not necessary here.

Comment: Between the names and the data there are 3 line breaks (With a whitespace in one of them) and 1 between each data row. There may or may not be a whitespace as the last data (It's accounted and expected). I knew that from the beginning and the code was made in order to clear all of that up leaving only the data from the lines that should be there. I'll edit the post to show that it's like after I process it. It shouldn't happen because the whitespaces that show up do so in places where they should have been processed if they were there (which they aren't) in the first place.

Comment: Just read your comment. That seems to have fixed it. I'll get back to you in a while after I try to confirm it.

Comment: It's working. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it. Maybe, if you can, explain why `$statisticsinput = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['statistics']);` was doing that but not `$statisticsinput = preg_replace('#\R+#', "\n", $_POST['statistics']); $statisticsinput = explode("\n", $statisticsinput);`

Comment: I have added an answer. Next time write more clear question. With simple debugging you could have find out that `preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['statistics']);` was giving you an array with empty cells, and all you had to do was giving us this line of code and ask why this happens, and how to avoid this.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did my best. I never suspected that preg_split was making the array act up because of how it only happened a hundred cycles later. That's why I didn't mention it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line of code that exploding the string into array was:

```
$statisticsinput = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $_POST['statistics']);
```

Which separate the array every time it finds in the string `\r\n` or `\r` or `\n`. Since you have in your string multiple line breaks in a row, it will obvoiusly make empty array cells.
So first of all we want to get rid of multiple line breaks, and only then explode it into array.

```
$statisticsinput = preg_replace('#\R+#', "\n", $_POST['statistics']); 
$statisticsinput = explode("\n", $statisticsinput);
```

That way you will not have empty array cells.

Note: `\R` matches `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n`.